# Ошибка создания динамического списка (List)

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, list, список

По непонятной мне причине я не могу создать динамический список (T), в то время как списки int, string и пр. создаются без возвращения ошибок. Вот код моей программы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 public class MyClass
    {
        public List<T> Items { get; set; } = new List<T>();
    }
```

Возвращается ошибка: **CS0246 "Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имён T"**

Что можно сделать в такой ситуации? SystemCollections.Generic я импортировал, список задан вроде как верно.

Comment: `public class MyClass<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Вы объявили свойство типа генерик(шаблонно) а сам тип шаблона не передаете, если бы это был генерик метод проблем не было б. При вызове метода требовалось бы указывать тип, а так как у Вас свойство то и класс делайте генерик:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Мой ответ может тебе не сильно помочь, т.к. я еще обучаюсь и пытаюсь разбираться в вопросах для саморазвития.

Мое предположение: в массиве ты указываешь List<типа массива> Имя массива

Соответственно и ошибка вызвана тем, что массива Т попросту не существует, работа может вестись только со значениями double,float,byte,long и т.д. Т.к. ты не обозначаешь какой тип данных будет храниться в массиве появляется ошибка.

Comment: Нет, на самом деле <T> связано с объявлением динамического массива.

Comment: <T> - как самостоятельной единицы не существует, это образное обозначения List<T> - где <T> является переменной на усмотрение пользователя, соответственно она должна идти под замену обозначения массива, т.к. он однородный, должно указываться в каком типе оно будет использоваться int, part и т.д. 

То есть в коде не может стоят предписание List<T>, а только List<int>, List<double> и т.д.

Comment: То есть для вас `<T>` это лишь обозначение в документации некого абстрактного типа коллекции, который каждый сам уже решает какой ему нужен? Я правильно понимаю? Другими словами [такой](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ETZCR) пример, это просто абстрактное обозначение и он не должен работать?